# How do you use Keras preprocessing.Normalization layers with multi-Input models and a Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

All the [documentation](https://keras.io/guides/preprocessing_layers/) for Keras pre-processing seems to assume a single `Input`. If you have a model with multiple `Input`s:

```
x_norm = preprocessing.Normalization()
y_norm = preprocessing.Normalization()

x = layers.Input(shape=(1,))
x = x_norm(x)
y = layers.Input(shape=(1,))
y = y_norm(y)
concated = layers.Concatenate()([x, y])
output = layers.Dense(1)(concated)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[x, y], outputs=output)
```

It's unclear how to use `adapt()` on a `Dataset` to "train" each preprocessing layer (i.e. `x_norm` and `y_norm`). With a single `Input` and preprocessing layer (e.g. `preprocessing_layer`) you simply do:

```
preprocessing_layer.adapt(dataset)
```

But in the case of multiple inputs how do I select the right input feature to use in `adapt()`?

Answer (score 0):

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
normalization_layers = {
    'x': preprocessing.Normalization(),
    'y': preprocessing.Normalization(),
    }
for batch in dataset:
  for name, layer in normalization_layers.items():
    layer.adapt(batch[0][name])
```

I don't know if this is efficient and TensorFlow gives a warning about a `tf.function` (inside `adapt()`) being called in a loop.